# Fetching errors after running grep command from java

Tags: java, bash, shell, grep

I am running grep command via my Java program. Running grep on the command line sometimes writes an error on stderr of the kind: `No such file or directory`. I want to detect in my Java program whenever this error happens as a result of executing the grep command via the program. How can I achieve this goal of mine? This is what I've written so far:

```
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "grep -c 'Search_String' /path/to/file(s)/being/searched"};
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason you can't check that the file exists before passing it to grep?

Comment: Check the exitValue. Grep returns 0 for success. If it returns a non-zero value, you're going to have to parse the output.

Comment: @JoeC I can check but this would make it more comfortable for me when I am trying to run the command against lots of files

Comment: @Dakoda how to check the exitValue here?

Comment: For your code: int retVal = proc.waitFor(); // wait for return value

Comment: Don't check Process.exitValue(). It won't be there until it returns.  It creates another Thread to execute the command. waitFor() will wait until it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect if the process returned with an error; as @Dakoda mentions, `exitValue()` won't have the exit value until the process ends, but using `waitFor()` will block until the process ends and returns the exit value:

```
int rv = rt.waitFor();
if (rv != 0) { ... }
```

Error output is usually on `stderr` rather than `stdout`, so to read errors you'd use:

```
BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));
```